# Detecting intervals of inactivity in the tty? (to simulate setterm --blank in fbterm)

Tags: terminal, tty, power-management, framebuffer

`setterm --blank n` allows me to configure the virtual terminal to automatically shut the display off after *n* minutes of inactivity. Unfortunately, I spend all my time in fbterm, where `setterm` does not apply.

I've found that I can manually shut the display off with

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:10.0/0000\:02\:00.0/graphics/fb0/blank'
```

(and `echo 0` to restore it).

Is there any way to detect periods of inactivity in the tty/fbterm, so that I can create a script to simulate a `setterm --blank` setting?

Comment: `setterm` command only work in /dev/tty* consoles, not from terminal emulators or terminal multiplexers.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question to reflect this understanding.